# Locate a point in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis

I use QGIS 2.18. I am new to geospatial data. I use a world map downloaded from the "Natural Earth" website (https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors). I would like to locate on this map a point whose coordinates I obtained from Wikipedia (https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?language=es&pagename=Alcazarquivir&params=35_N_-5.9_E_type:city), specifically is the location of "Alcazarquivir" (35 °, -5.9 °). For me to locate this point I create a new vector layer but when I position the point the point appears in the wrong place.

The CRS of the Natural Earth dataset is: + proj = longlat + datum = WGS84 + no_defs. To add the point:

1- I created a new Shapefile layer of type point. I named this layer "Point". In the Metadata item in "Layer Spatial Reference System" of the new layer it appears: + Proj = longlat + datum = WGS84 + no_defs

2- I put the "Point" layer in edit mode

3- Then, I added a new point using the "Add feature" option. I put this new point in a randomly chosen location.

4- Then using the Numerical Vertex Edit tool (plugin: Numerical Vertex Edit) I entered the exact coordinates of the point: 35 °, -5.9 °, these coordinates correspond to Alcazarquivir in Morocco, but it appears in the wrong location as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify *how* you created this new layer and *which* wrong place it appears in. The coordinate reference system (CRS) of the Natural Earth dataset, the map canvas, and the newly created layer are all likely to be important.

Comment: The X coordinate of the point is its longitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are entering the inversed coordinates, in the fields of the vertex editor.

Beyond the order of the axes that is defined in the coordinate reference system, in the vertex editor the axes are defined by name as X and Y.

In that case, the X coordinate corresponds to the longitude or easting, which in your case should be -5.9. And the Y coordinate corresponds to the latitude or norting, which in your case should be 35.